# Convert collection objects one type to objects another using Stream API and reference methods

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I use lambda to convert objects one type to objects another

- Order

```java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "order")
public class Order {

    private String customer;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "orderItem")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public Order() {
    }
```

- OrderDto

```java
public class OrderDto {

     private String customer;

     private String orderXml;

    public OrderDto() {
    }
```

- service

```java
@Service
public class OrderReadServiceImpl implements OrderReadService {

    private OrderEntityRepository repository;

    private OrderDtoMapper mapper;

    private CycleAvoidingMappingContext context;

    @Autowired
    public OrderReadServiceImpl(OrderEntityRepository repository,
                                OrderDtoMapper mapper,
                                CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Order> getListOrder() {

        Iterable<OrderEntity> orderEntities = this.repository.findAll();

        Iterable<Order> orders = convertXmlToListObj(orderEntities);

        return orders;
    }

    private Iterable<Order> convertXmlToListObj(Iterable<OrderEntity> entities) {

        Iterable<OrderDto> dtoList = toListDto(entities);

        Iterable<Order> orders = convertListToList(dtoList);

        return orders;
    }

    /**
     * There is convert a collection of objects one type to another type
     * @param dtoList
     * @return
     */
    private static Iterable<Order> convertListToList(Iterable<OrderDto> dtoList) {

        List<OrderDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        dtoList.forEach(list::add);

        List<Order> collect = list.stream()
            .map(orderDto -> {
                Order order = convertXmlToObj(orderDto);
                return order;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return collect;
    }

    /**
     * there is got a string that xml. This xml is convert to java object
     * @param orderDto
     * @return
     */
    private static Order convertXmlToObj(OrderDto orderDto) {

        String orderXml = orderDto.getOrderXml();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(orderXml);

        Order order = JAXB.unmarshal(reader, Order.class);

        return order;
    }

    /**
     * transform objects of  entity type to objects of dto types
     * @param entities
     * @return
     */
    private Iterable<OrderDto> toListDto(Iterable<OrderEntity> entities) {
        return this.mapper.toListDto(entities);
    }
}
```

The resulting list of entities is converted to a **dto** collection. The collection of the converted dto list is iterated over and retrieved from there **xml** from the field of each collection element and then the structure of this **xml** it will be umarshall (that is, the list of **xml** elements will be converted to the collection of java objects)

```java
        List<OrderDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        dtoList.forEach(list::add);

        List<Order> collect = list.stream()
            .map(orderDto -> {
                Order order = convertXmlToObj(orderDto);
                return order;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return collect;
```

I would desire to do simplest. I want the code to will be yet lesser.

Сan you remove the code somewhere, how to reduce it.

I mean . Where do I create the 'method references' yet.

Who has any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the `Iterable` to `Stream` directly, without creating a `List`:

```
StreamSupport.stream(dtoList.spliterator(), false)
```

Your code can become

```
private static Iterable<Order> convertListToList(Iterable<OrderDto> dtoList) 
{
    return StreamSupport.stream(dtoList.spliterator(), false)
        .map(orderDto -> convertXmlToObj(orderDto))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or with method reference:

```
private static Iterable<Order> convertListToList(Iterable<OrderDto> dtoList) 
{
    return StreamSupport.stream(dtoList.spliterator(), false)
        .map(OrderReadServiceImpl::convertXmlToObj)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

BTW, since your method is named `convertListToList()`, perhaps it should accept and return `List`s instead of `Iterable`s.

Comment: It is great. Thank you.

Comment: I get the result into endpoint Rest-service. ( @GetMapping(path = "read", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public Iterable<Order> getList(){})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem of mapping objects in general and are not looking exactly for an optimization of your lambda/stream solution, you could give [MapStruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct) a look. Simplified description: It generates mappers with the help of annotations at compile time.

Comment: I use MapStruct, but for this task I don't know how to apply it